# Using Filewatcher for a progress bar with subdirectories, Wont Update Properly

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to copy Files from a local Computer to a Network device. I'm trying to get a Progress Bar working for the File copy, and got it working for a Single Directory with no Subdirectory:

```
Private Sub CopyPictures()
    Try                          
     If Not Directory.Exists(DestinationPath) Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(DestinationPath)
     End If
            Dim counterLocalFiles = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(SourcePath)
            UpdateProgressBarMaximum1(CInt(counterLocalFiles.Count))
            UpdateLabelText2(CStr(counterLocalFiles.Count)) 'is a label which shows copied X files of Label2 Files

            fsw1 = New IO.FileSystemWatcher(DestinationPath)
            fsw1.EnableRaisingEvents = True

            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(SourcePath, DestinationPath)

            GetSettingsFromFile()            
    Catch Exec As System.IO.IOException
        Dim dr As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Some Random Error Code", "Exception Title", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
        If (Not DialogResult.OK = dr) Then
            Exit Sub
        Return
End If
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub fsw1_Created(sender As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs) Handles fsw1.Created
    Dim counterRemoteFiles = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(DestinationPath)
    UpdateProgressBar1(CInt(counterRemoteFiles.Count))
    UpdateLabelText1(CStr(counterRemoteFiles.Count))
End Sub
```

The Update ObjectX Subs are just invoke Functions since the CopyPictures is raised by a backgroundworker as well looking all like this one for example

```
Private Sub UpdateProgressBar1(Value As Int32)
    If ProgressBar1.InvokeRequired Then
        ProgressBar1.Invoke(New Action(Of Integer)(AddressOf UpdateProgressBar1), Value)
    Else
        'We are on the UI thread so update the control.
        ProgressBar1.Value = Value
    End If
End Sub
```

This code works perfectly fine for me, but I have to deal with SubDirectories which contain the Images, and the names of the subs are random so i cant predetermine them so I came up with slight changes:

The Counter is looking now like this:

```
Dim counterLocalFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.jpg*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length
            UpdateProgressBarMaximum1(CInt(counterLocalFiles))
            UpdateLabelText2(CStr(counterLocalFiles))
```

And this:

```
Dim counterRemoteFiles = IO.Directory.GetFiles(DestinationPath, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length
    UpdateProgressBar1(CInt(counterRemoteFiles))
    UpdateLabelText1(CStr(counterRemoteFiles))
```

And I added:

```
fsw1.IncludeSubdirectories = True
```

Now the weired Problems started: It would properly count the file in the source Directory setting label2 to the correct amount of files in all subdirectories and then start copying. It would NOT update the Progressbar though in real time. It just updated it once when it was done with the first directory and just adding the amount of files to it which it contained. After that it completly stoppedd nored the second directory and didn't add that at all to the progressbar. What am I doing wrong here? I hope my english is fine, If you have any question or If I was not clear enough, please let me know. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an event consumer that triggers your progressbar update routine - you call it once when your filesystemwatcher is instantiated.

You need to declare an event that handles the copy event and fires off your progress update code. Because Filesystemwatcher cannot monitor network drives, you may want to declare an event that fires off your progress update method when the counterRemoteFiles count increments.

Comment: But why does it work completly fine if I use the code without a subdirectory? It works the complete same way but without taking the subdirectories into considdrrations for the counters.

Comment: I suggest some line by line debugging whereby you can watch your variables...this will help immensely. If you are working in VS, you can right click and set a breakpoint in your code and the run your code in "start debugging" mode and it will halt execution at your breakpoint and allow stepping from there...you can step over (F10) or step into (F11) your code. while stepping over/into you can float over variables and objects and view their values/states; and you can right click on vars and add them as "watched" items for viewing while in debugging mode.

Comment: And I use the systemfilewatcher somewhere else in the program to monitor the change of a settings file which is on //foo/bar and that as well works just fine. I'm new to vb.net so i may be doing something fundametly wrong here but I cant see it

Comment: Ok, i will do that tomorrow when iget back on my machine. The main thing was just that i cant get it why its not working with the subdirectories but was working fine without.

Comment: Does FSW do network drives now? Anyway, debug and isolate sections so that you can systematically verify which parts work as intended and which do not...you can solve this :)

Comment: Allright so I did some line by line debugging, and it revealed that, the filesystemwatcher only fires when a subdirectory is created in the DestinationPath. It completly ignores file creations. I debugged the Version without subdirectories, and that worked completly as intented, the Filewatcher would always fire when a file is created. But why isnt it working like this if I do fsw1.IncludeSubidrectories = true. It seems to completely ignore that. (btw im testing it on local drives) How can I set up the SystemFileWatcher properly to accept Subdirectories?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just made a mistake with correctly putting the

```
fsw1.IncludeSubdirectories = True
```

I was setting it to true in the Form Editor instead of doing it in the code. Once i actually put that in the code after initialising the fsw, it would work just fine